# Uploading File in Ajax Spring MVC Not Working

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am uploading a file using ajax to spring mvc controller using the following code

```
var formData = new FormData();    
formData.append('file', file);

  $.ajax({
         url: url,
         data: formData,
         cache: false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         type: 'POST',
     });
```

I can see my data in the http post but i am getting null value in controller.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/file.htm" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public @ResponseBody String upload(@RequestParam(value="file",required=false) CommonsMultipartFile file 

            ) throws IOException {

        String response="";
}
```

I have tried with `MultipartFile` also. I have even tried to use `MultipartHttpServletRequest` and tried to obtain data from the request but cannot get it. Please let me know how to resolve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try use @RequestPart instead of @RequestParam

Comment: I could still see the post data in the firebug console..but the value of the parameter "file" is still NULL in the controller..i am struggling with this for 2 days. please help..

Answer (score 1):

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append( "file", $("input[name=file]").files[0]);

var ajaxReq =  $.ajax({
    url : 'kolfileUpload',
    type : 'POST',
    data : fd,
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,

});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.